# "MemoryAllocationFailure" in DSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, warning-messages

Mathematica 10.4, Windows 10, 6 GB RAM, 64 bits

When I trying to solve

```
DSolve[{v'[t] == 100 - 0.15 v[t]^2, v[0] == 30}, v[t], t]
```

I get `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`

```
NDSolve[{v'[t] == 100 - 0.15 v[t]^2, v[0] == 30}, v[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

working without any problems.

**Questions:** Can this equation be solved analytically? Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: Use `15/100` instead of `0.15`.  Approximate real numbers can sometimes bog down exact solvers.  (`DSolve` and `NDSolve` do not have a lot in common in terms of algorithms used, so I'm not surprised at the difference.)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's a bug, but *Mathematica* makes a move that, when it's your student you say, why did you do that! It was simpler before.

I ran this code without the replacement with `Exp[stuff__ * C[1]]` in order to figure out what to do to fix it.  (The colored output below are from the `Print` statements showing the various calls to `Solve` that happen inside `DSolve`.)

```
Module[{$inside, res, $stuff},
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
  Unprotect[Solve];
  Solve[sys_, vars_, opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$inside] := 
   Block[{$inside = True},
    res = Solve[
      sys /. Exp[stuff__*C[1]] :> ($stuff = Times[stuff]; C[2]),
      vars /. C[1] -> C[2],
      Reals, opts];
    Print[sys -> res];
    If[FreeQ[res, C[2]],
     res,
     Print["Rewritten: ", (sys /. Exp[stuff__*C[1]] :> C[2]) -> res];
     {C[1] -> Log[C[2]]/$stuff} /. res]
    ];
  Protect[Solve];
  DSolve[Rationalize@{v'[t] == 100 - 0.15 v[t]^2, v[0] == 30}, v, t]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* solution:
  {{v -> Function[{t}, (20 (-10 + 3 Sqrt[15] + 10 E^(2 Sqrt[15] t) + 
         3 Sqrt[15] E^(2 Sqrt[15] t)))/(-9 + 2 Sqrt[15] + 
       9 E^(2 Sqrt[15] t) + 2 Sqrt[15] E^(2 Sqrt[15] t))]}}
*)
```

You can see in the yellow call to `Solve`, the equation is in the perfect state to solve for the constant of integration `C[1]`.  But through exponentiation we get an expression for `v` that has 40 complex solutions to the initial condition:

```
DSolve[Rationalize@{v'[t] == 100 - 0.15 v[t]^2, v[0] == 30}, v, t]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*
{{v -> Function[{t}, (
    20 Sqrt[5/3] (-1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - (I π + Log[1/7 (47 - 12 Sqrt[15])])/(
          2 Sqrt[15])))))/(
    1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - (I π + Log[1/7 (47 - 12 Sqrt[15])])/(2 Sqrt[15]))))]}, 
 ...38 solutions omitted..,
 {v -> 
   Function[{t}, (20 Sqrt[5/3] (-1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - 
          4 Sqrt[5/3]Log[(-1)^(19/20) (1/7 (-47 + 12 Sqrt[15]))^(1/40)]))))/(
    1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - 4 Sqrt[5/3] *
      Log[(-1)^(19/20) (1/7 (-47 + 12 Sqrt[15]))^(1/40)])))]}}
*)
```

You might be better off solving the initial condition by itself:

```
dsol = DSolve[Rationalize@{v'[t] == 100 - 0.15 v[t]^2}, v[t], t]
(*
  {{v[t] -> (20 Sqrt[5/3] (-1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - 20 C[1]))))/(
     1 + E^(2 Sqrt[15] (t - 20 C[1])))}}
*)
```

Solving the initial condition for `C[1]` has to be done over the complex numbers.  This introduces a free parameter which can be given any integer value, since they are all equivalent real solutions.

```
Solve[v[t] == 30 /. First@dsol /. t -> 0, C[1]]
icsol = % /. C[2] -> 0 // Simplify
(*
  {{C[1] -> 
     ConditionalExpression[(
      I π + 2 I π C[2] + Log[-((-9 + 2 Sqrt[15])/(9 + 2 Sqrt[15]))])/(40 Sqrt[15]), 
      C[2] ∈ Integers]}}

  {{C[1] -> (I π + Log[1/7 (47 - 12 Sqrt[15])])/(40 Sqrt[15])}}
*)
```

Finally, plug `C[1]` into the general solution:

```
dsol0 = dsol /. First@icsol // Simplify
(*
  {{v[t] -> (20 Sqrt[5/3] (7 + (47 + 12 Sqrt[15]) E^(2 Sqrt[15] t))) / 
       (-7 + (47 + 12 Sqrt[15]) E^(2 Sqrt[15] t))}}
*)
```