# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] with DSolve and using TimeConstrained

Tags: differential-equations, memory, crash

Report to WRI **CASE:4238154**

---

There is a similar question where `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` is generated by `DSolve` here [memoryallocationfailure-in-dsolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112818/memoryallocationfailure-in-dsolve) but that due to user using real number and not exact in the ODE.

I am getting `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` where there are no real values in it. And the problem seem to happen when wrapping the call by `TimeConstrained` to limit the time used, which is very strange.

From a clean kernel

```
pde = a*D[w[x, y], x] + b*Sinh[lambda*x]*D[w[x, y], y] == 
   c*Sinh[mu*x]^m + s*Sinh[beta*y]^k;
sol = TimeConstrained[DSolve[pde, w[x, y], {x, y}], 60*10]
```

And on my PC, after about only 3 minutes, I get

```
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. 
      Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].
```

And again, from clean kernel, doing this

```
pde = a*D[w[x, y], x] + b*Sinh[lambda*x]*D[w[x, y], y] == 
   c*Sinh[mu*x]^m + s*Sinh[beta*y]^k;
DSolve[pde, w[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Produces no error, but it hangs. I waited for 15 minutes and nothing happened. No crash and no result. So I terminate the kernel to stop it.

Why would using `TimeConstrained` cause this? I think this is a bug, but would like to know if others confirm it before I send bug report to WRI.

Using 11.3 on windows 10 pro, with 64 GB RAM.

Comment: Well, it crashed my FE....